# its possible dont show error from DataAnnotations with element hidden?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

After hide element with

```
 $("#element").hide();
```

When it come back

```
$("#element").show();
```

any error from DataAnnotations to be continued displayed, is there a way, to dont show error in this case?

Comment: So you do not want to show validation error messages when the form is submitted ? I am confused about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Not exactly, i need the validations reset, If the user resumes the search from the beginning.

Comment: Yes. You should be able to update the DOM as needed at client side. Check the element(which shows the validation message) before and after, so you know what needs to be reset(the visibility,css class and the content may be)

Comment: You need some type of validation element to show the data annotation, why do you just wrap them both in a div and hide that div instead?